Add IP address with CIDR mask to nftables set in Go
adding a regular IP address (for example fe80::1 or 127.0.0.1) to an nftables set works by parsing the address with net.ParseIP and then converting it to []bytes for listing as a Key in a []nftables.SetElement object.
I would like to do the same with an IP address containing a CIDR mask (for example fe80::1/64 or 127.0.0.1/24).
I tried parsing it with net.ParseCIDR, and using the resulting *net.IPNet object (in the example below referred to as ipCidr), but it cannot be converted to bytes. The .Mask attribute can, but contains only the subnet mask. The .Network() function can too, but yields conn.Receive: netlink receive: invalid argument if attempted to be added to a set.
Expected result as with the nft command line:
# nft add element inet filter foo '{ fe80::1/64 }'
# nft list set inet filter foo
table inet filter {
        set foo {
                type ipv6_addr
                flags interval
                elements = { fe80::/64 }
        }
}

Sample program:
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "github.com/google/nftables"
    "log"
    "net"
    "strings"
)

func demo(givenAddress string) error {
    nft, err := nftables.New()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    targetTable := "filter"

    foundTables, err := nft.ListTables()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    exists := false
    var table *nftables.Table
    for _, foundTable := range foundTables {
        if foundTable.Name == targetTable {
            exists = true
            table = foundTable
            break
        }
    }

    if !exists {
        return errors.New("Table filter does not exist")
    }

    set, err := nft.GetSetByName(table, "foo")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var element []nftables.SetElement
    var elementEntry []byte

    if strings.Contains(givenAddress, "/") {
        _, ipCidr, err := net.ParseCIDR(givenAddress)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        // this is the problematic part
        elementEntry = []byte(ipCidr.Network())
        //
    } else {
        ip := net.ParseIP(givenAddress)
        elementEntry = []byte(ip)
    }

    element = []nftables.SetElement{
        {
            Key: elementEntry,
        },
    }

    err = nft.SetAddElements(set, element)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err = nft.Flush()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    address := "fe80::1/128"
    if err := demo(address); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}

